# Header whitespace

Tags: header

I have just started with a magento website with a templatemonster theme. I am having a problem with whitespace at the top of the page above the header. See url: http://testnation.eu/magento/index.php/

Can anyone advise how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra < p > tag in the content that is causing extra space.  **style.css** `491`

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

extra `<p>` tag

```
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript">// &lt;![CDATA[
    jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#camera_wrap').camera({
                alignmen: 'topCenter',
                height: '65%',
                minHeight: '100px',
                loader : false,
                navigation: true,
                fx: 'simpleFade',
                navigationHover:false,       
                thumbnails: false,
                playPause: false,
                pagination:false,
                onEndTransition: function() {
                    jQuery('.camera_caption h4').removeClass('animated');
                    jQuery('.camera_caption h4').addClass('animated'); 
                    jQuery('.camera_caption span').removeClass('animated');
                    jQuery('.camera_caption span').addClass('animated');
                    jQuery('.camera_caption a').removeClass('animated');
                    jQuery('.camera_caption a').addClass('animated');
                }
            });
        });
    // ]]&gt;</script>
    </p>
```

Comment: Thank you. Where exactly do I need to remove the extra <p> tag...? In styless.css or? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually sorted it now. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @ScottHumphris if you find this answer help kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Magento1 check your theme's `[...]/template/page/html/head.phtml` to see if there aren't any leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

For the quick fix you can do

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Then you should dig, from where the margin gets applied.